# How to connect a routinator to a slef-hosted krill testbed server?

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate

Overall Goal is to connect routinator with a self-hosted krill in testbed mode, and publish self-defined ROAs.
Krill(A) and routinator(B) runs on different machines.

On Krill(A), a self-signed certificated is used as CA's root certificate. Using the root certificate, another certificate is signed for the hostname "krill.com" for the http server. The http server certificate files(`key.pem` and `cer.pem`) are located in  `/var/krill/data/ssl/`
Config of krill(A):

```
# Global configuration
verbose = true
port=3000
ip = "0.0.0.0"
https_mode = "existing"
log_file = "/var/krill/logs/krill.log"
data_dir = "/var/krill/data"
log_type = "file"
log_level = "debug"
admin_token ="krill"
# Configure the ROA repository
[roa_repository]
# # Use the file system backend
backend = "fs"
# # Use a local directory for the repository
directory = "/var/krill/data/roa"

[testbed]

rrdp_base_uri = "https://krill.com:3000/rrdp/"
rsync_jail = "rsync://krill.com/repo/"
ta_aia = "rsync://krill.com/repo/ta.cer"
ta_uri = "https://krill.com:3000/ta/ta.cer"
```

On routinator(B), the `/etc/hosts` is modified to pointing the hostname(`krill.com`) to A's IP.
Before starting routinator: 1) TAL file is downloaded and added. 2) the CA's certificate is added to `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` with command `update-ca-certificates`
Config of routinator(B):

```
repository-dir = "/var/routinator/data"

# Do not use bundled RIR TALs.
no-rir-tals = true

extra-tals-dir = "/var/routinator/tals/"

allow-dubious-hosts = true



refresh = 20
retry = 10

expire = 10

rtr-listen = ["0.0.0.0:3323"]

http-listen = ["0.0.0.0:9556"]

log-level = "debug"

log = "file"


# Log file
#
# The path to the file to log to if file logging is used. If the path is
# relative, it is relative to the directory this config file lives in.
log-file = "/var/routinator/logs/routinator.log"
```

**Problem**
I got `invalid peer certificate: UnknownIssuer` on routinator.
log on B:

```
[2023-04-14 09:11:01] [INFO] Starting a validation run.
[2023-04-14 09:11:01] [INFO] Using the following TALs:
[2023-04-14 09:11:01] [INFO]   * afrinic
[2023-04-14 09:11:01] [INFO]   * krill
[2023-04-14 09:11:01] [INFO] rsyncing from rsync://krill.com/repo/.
[2023-04-14 09:11:01] [DEBUG] rsync://krill.com/repo/: Running command Command { std: "rsync" "--contimeout=10" "--max-size=20000000" "-rltz" "--delete" "rsync://krill.com/repo/" "/var/routinator/data/rsync/krill.com/repo/", kill_on_drop: false }
[2023-04-14 09:11:01] [DEBUG] Found valid trust anchor rsync://krill.com/repo/ta.cer. Processing.
[2023-04-14 09:11:01] [WARN] RRDP https://krill.com:3000/rrdp/notification.xml: error sending request for url (https://krill.com:3000/rrdp/notification.xml): error trying to connect: invalid peer certificate contents: invalid peer certificate: UnknownIssuer
[2023-04-14 09:11:01] [INFO] RRDP https://krill.com:3000/rrdp/notification.xml: Update failed and there is no current copy.
[2023-04-14 09:11:01] [INFO] RRDP https://krill.com:3000/rrdp/notification.xml: Falling back to rsync.
[2023-04-14 09:11:03] [DEBUG] Found valid trust anchor https://rpki.afrinic.net/repository/AfriNIC.cer. Processing.
[2023-04-14 09:11:06] [DEBUG] RRDP https://rrdp.afrinic.net/notification.xml: updating from snapshot.
[2023-04-14 09:11:18] [DEBUG] RRDP https://rrdp.afrinic.net/notification.xml: snapshot update completed.
[2023-04-14 09:11:18] [WARN] rsync://rpki.afrinic.net/repository/member_repository/F368F2D0/92F86E1C6E0511E8A1B5854BF8AEA228/5F5E1EA2CE0F11EDAFC21BEEF1222468.roa: certificate is not yet valid.
[2023-04-14 09:11:18] [WARN] rsync://rpki.afrinic.net/repository/member_repository/F36432B6/0E94184AB75911EDA15F2C90F1222468/e9fVVRg6gfgLprfZNoeRJF7Y0z4.mft: no valid manifest found.
[2023-04-14 09:11:18] [WARN] rsync://rpki.afrinic.net/repository/member_repository/F36EC460/982107B4898111EC906D03B45A40D577/06A95068899811ECAECD6D765A40D577.roa: certificate is overclaiming IPv4 resources.
[2023-04-14 09:11:18] [WARN] rsync://rpki.afrinic.net/repository/member_repository/F36886B3/5A411F9EB8EF11EDA5B09DDAF1222468/mxi9dO1YDbl9W9qdlXDKFpcMy8w.mft: no valid manifest found.
[2023-04-14 09:11:19] [WARN] rsync://rpki.afrinic.net/repository/member_repository/F36EE1C1/050BE1D635B311ED9721E3F0F1222468/V00kEnto5oHJEhRaMMayIbP4KlA.mft: no valid manifest found.
[2023-04-14 09:11:19] [WARN] rsync://rpki.afrinic.net/repository/member_repository/F36EE1C1/050BE1D635B311ED9721E3F0F1222468/STmJqI9ygR8i60Gk6wwSdOHx2pA.mft: no valid manifest found.
[2023-04-14 09:11:19] [WARN] rsync://rpki.afrinic.net/repository/member_repository/F36549B1/DF788C98561311E5B1A0E360F8AEA228/FB0E15F8CAB911E9AA072951F8AEA228.roa: certificate is overclaiming IPv4 resources.
[2023-04-14 09:11:19] [WARN] rsync://rpki.afrinic.net/repository/member_repository/F36EE1C1/050BE1D635B311ED9721E3F0F1222468/0YiYIkQP2ghuQ_3L-e-Gb9Uepbw.mft: no valid manifest found.
[2023-04-14 09:11:19] [WARN] rsync://rpki.afrinic.net/repository/member_repository/F36EE1C1/050BE1D635B311ED9721E3F0F1222468/6n6vYSDTEzssFOqYEf97HcuEQhE.mft: no valid manifest found.
[2023-04-14 09:11:19] [WARN] rsync://rpki.afrinic.net/repository/member_repository/F36505B2/0569917622D711ED862FD6E0F1222468/z1Kz6_gz2w85Tz77x4mC_9aJbxA.mft: no valid manifest found.
[2023-04-14 09:11:19] [WARN] rsync://rpki.afrinic.net/repository/member_repository/F36EE1C1/050BE1D635B311ED9721E3F0F1222468/BpTOBmDPIzc01Obno4jqMUHuRbk.mft: no valid manifest found.
[2023-04-14 09:11:19] [WARN] rsync://rpki.afrinic.net/repository/member_repository/F36EE1C1/050BE1D635B311ED9721E3F0F1222468/YmFCTuhQuS5FxpB3tvSkzniKeJM.mft: no valid manifest found.
[2023-04-14 09:11:19] [WARN] rsync://rpki.afrinic.net/repository/member_repository/F36EE1C1/050BE1D635B311ED9721E3F0F1222468/S4D0bEIIq3jyH3EKKWI1-QYyTis.mft: no valid manifest found.
[2023-04-14 09:11:19] [WARN] rsync://rpki.afrinic.net/repository/member_repository/F36EC460/ACEC2D22898111EC95D350B45A40D577/AAFC7F38899711EC8B6754755A40D577.roa: certificate is overclaiming IPv4 resources.
[2023-04-14 09:11:19] [WARN] rsync://rpki.afrinic.net/repository/member_repository/F36EE1C1/050BE1D635B311ED9721E3F0F1222468/vJWioqaGyUWVsW4DMK6ROPdodIg.mft: no valid manifest found.
[2023-04-14 09:11:19] [WARN] rsync://rpki.afrinic.net/repository/member_repository/F366B0C9/F126518CBC4011EDAB594EDCF1222468/2FBDFB28BC4311EDA72CEEE2F1222468.roa: certificate is not yet valid.
[2023-04-14 09:11:19] [WARN] rsync://rpki.afrinic.net/repository/member_repository/F36EE1C1/050BE1D635B311ED9721E3F0F1222468/uMx4HMq3HaLS0ZoP0TbJGEBE2zA.mft: no valid manifest found.
[2023-04-14 09:11:19] [INFO] Validation completed.
[2023-04-14 09:11:19] [INFO] Summary at 2023-04-14 09:11:01.530920408 UTC
[2023-04-14 09:11:19] [INFO] afrinic: 
[2023-04-14 09:11:19] [INFO]             ROAs:    3632 verified;
[2023-04-14 09:11:19] [INFO]             VRPs:    4978 verified,    4853 final;
[2023-04-14 09:11:19] [INFO]     router certs:       0 verified;
[2023-04-14 09:11:19] [INFO]      router keys:       0 verified,       0 final.
[2023-04-14 09:11:19] [INFO] krill: 
[2023-04-14 09:11:19] [INFO]             ROAs:       0 verified;
[2023-04-14 09:11:19] [INFO]             VRPs:       0 verified,       0 final;
[2023-04-14 09:11:19] [INFO]     router certs:       0 verified;
[2023-04-14 09:11:19] [INFO]      router keys:       0 verified,       0 final.
[2023-04-14 09:11:19] [INFO] total: 
[2023-04-14 09:11:19] [INFO]             ROAs:    3632 verified;
[2023-04-14 09:11:19] [INFO]             VRPs:    4978 verified,    4853 final;
[2023-04-14 09:11:19] [INFO]     router certs:       0 verified;
[2023-04-14 09:11:19] [INFO]      router keys:       0 verified,       0 final.
[2023-04-14 09:11:19] [INFO] New serial is 0.
[2023-04-14 09:11:19] [INFO] Sending out notifications.
```

Answer (score 0):

In the log: `invalid peer certificate contents: invalid peer certificate: UnknownIssuer` suggesting a certificate issue.

I tried a few days and found out that you need to add the certificate of the CA, who issued the certificate of Krill server, to the trusted certificates list on routinator (B) to solve this problem.